# How to SELECT from table A where it matches all guids belonging to a specific client from table B

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables; A and B.  Table A contains a column of GUIDs.  Table B contains a column of GUIDs and a column of ClientIDs.  In table B, the ClientIDs may be matched to multiple GUIDs.  If given 1 GUID, how would I select all GUIDs from table A that belong to the same ClientID as the given GUID?

For Example, if Table A has three rows:

```
Row1 | 11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555  
Row2 | 22222222-3333-4444-5555-666666666666  
Row3 | 33333333-4444-5555-6666-777777777777
```

Table B has 3 rows:

```
Row1 | ClientA | 11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555  
Row2 | ClientB | 22222222-3333-4444-5555-666666666666  
Row3 | ClientA | 33333333-4444-5555-6666-777777777777
```

I am given a GUID (`11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555`), how would I write a select statement to find all GUIDs from A that match the ClientID from Table B? (`11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555` & `33333333-4444-5555-6666-777777777777`)

Comment: What does TableA contribute? Are there cases where Table B has a row (ClientA, someGuidNotInTableA) ?

Comment: Correct.  There may several GUIDs in Table B belonging to ClientA that are not in TableA.

Comment: If you are *given* a specific GUID, how does Table A come into play? You need to verify that the given GUID belongs to Table A before proceeding with searching Table B for it?

Comment: I am working specifically with table A.  Table B contains all the GUIDs a few applications use.  My application uses table A, and because Clients may have multiple GUIDs, I need to check to see which GUID belongs to whom, so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eh, how about first finding the client with the given guid from table b

```
SELECT client FROM table_b WHERE guid = <given_guid>
```

and then getting all guid's for that client from table b

```
SELECT guid FROM table_b WHERE client = <client>
```

I mean you could do it in one go using subqueries

```
SELECT guid FROM table_b WHERE client IN ( 
    SELECT client FROM table_b WHERE guid = <given_guid>
)
```

but why complicate things

If you need additional data from table a for the guid's for clients, you can either `JOIN` or use the above as another subquery, e.g.

```
SELECT guid FROM table_a WHERE guid IN (
    SELECT guid FROM table_b WHERE client IN ( 
        SELECT client FROM table_b WHERE guid = <given_guid>
    )
)
```

p.s. I hate using subqueries, there almost always is a better way

Comment: Thanks!  I always overthink and over complicate things.  I was trying to do everything in 1 SELECT statement when it wasn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a_guid
  FROM TableA
INTERSECT 
SELECT a_guid
  FROM TableB
 WHERE ClientID IN ( SELECT ClientID
                       FROM TableB
                      WHERE a_guid = @given_guid );
```